# java generics <T extends >

Tags: java, class, generics, java-8

There is a parameter Class t in TestClass. t can not be assigned to ClassA.class?

```
puclic class TestClass<T extends ClassA>{
     private Class<T> t;
     public TestClass(Class<T> t){
        //this.t = ClassA.class;  // why not?
        this.t = t;
     }
}
```

but,Can be imported from outside。

```
public class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
              TestClass tc = new TestClass(ClassA.class);//It's ok
        }
}
```

I hope it can also be assigned internally！

Comment: In the `TestClass` constructor, it's not up to you what type `T` is, so you can't assume that `ClassA` is suitable. In your `main` it *is* up to you, and you're using a raw type so you're giving up on type-checking anyway.

Comment: You are using your own generic class as a raw type and therefor completly disabling the generic part of it. You should rather do `TestClass<ClassA> tc = new TestClass<>(ClassA.class);` The point of generic classes is that the one using them can declare the type. You could have a `ClassB extends ClassA` and then when creating your Testclass use the generics to declare that its generic type has to be ClassB `new TestClass<ClassB>`. As the actual type of `this.t` is dynamic you can't simply treat it as always being of `ClassA`, it can also be anything that extends that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generics on `j.l.Class` are used solely so that the expression `thatClass.newInstance()` has type `T`, e.g. that you can do:

```
Class<String> c = ...;
String x = c.newInstance();
```

If you know that, and you think it through, your human brain, with all that contextual knowledge of what it is used for, realizes that this:

```
Class<Child> childClass = ...;
Class<Parent> parentClass = childClass;
```

is completely safe.

**But javac cannot draw this conclusion**. Javac is not going to be a walking dictionary of the uses of generics for each and every class that uses it. It just knows that generics **generally** would be unsafe if you allow this; it simply doesn't know that the unsafe situations do not occur for any usages of j.l.Class.

It occurs with lists, quite easily. here:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> nums = ints;
Number n = 5.0; // a double
assert n instanceof Double; // true, of course.
nums.add(n); // legal java, of course.
Integer i = ints.get(0); // um.. wait. uhoh.
```

Think long and hard about the above snippet. Write it in java code and try to compile it. It is the key to understanding the fundamental tenet that generics are **invariant** - a subtype is NOT assignable to the supertype, not when the types we are looking at are *inside* the `<>`. You can replace: `List<Number>` with `List<? extends Number>` and then compilation gets further, but now `.add()` fails (and in fact, you can't add anything to a `List<? extends Whatever>`, except literally `null`.

Comment: You can not assume to know all uses of `Class` either. I can easily add another use case, e.g. write a method `<T> void method(Class<T> c, T obj) { … }` and the assumption that `T` is an instance of `Class<T>` would be violated if assigning `Class<Child>` to `Class<Parent>` was allowed.